# accessing lang variables from controller + codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, controller

How can I access my lang variables in controller?

```
function index()  
{   
    $seo_title = $this->lang->line('blablabla');
    $data['page_title'] =  $seo_title;  
    $this->load->view('contact/index.php',$data);  
}
```

in my lang file blablabla has string in, and it works well when I call from view file. but when I want to call from controller, it doesnt return anything :(

any idea about problem? appreciate!!

Answer (score 4):

You need to [load the language file](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/language.html) you want to use before you grab lines from it:

```
$this->lang->load('filename', 'language');
```